# Updating to NULL in DateTime Field

Tags: php, sql, datetime, null

I am using PHP and SQL through an ODBC connection to update a DateTime field that had a date in it to NULL. The field can be NULL I know that. I have tried setting it NULL with and without quotes but still no success. I know the SQL works because if I input a date instead of NULL it works. Any help would be amazing.

```
$dateapproved = "NULL";
$updatedateapprovedsql = "UPDATE [Problem Data Table] SET [Corrective action approved]='$dateapproved' WHERE [8D Number]='$pionumber'";
$updatedateapprovedresult=odbc_exec($connection,$updatedateapprovedsql);
```

Comment: How well do you know that the field can be `NULL`? You should be able to insert/update a null value without problems like this `SET date = NULL`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the apostrophes around the null value:

```
$updatedateapprovedsql = "UPDATE [Problem Data Table] SET [Corrective action approved] = null WHERE [8D Number]='$pionumber'";
```

Comment: Thanks. That was part of the problem it appeared else where in the code I was using `date_create` so when it returned a NULL field I was actually getting a date which confused me.

Comment: In codeigniter it seems to accept $updateData['expires_on'] = null without throwing an error and it works like charm. But if you use $updateData['expires_on'] = 'null' You are bound to end up in a date with '0000-00-00 00:00:00' than Null..!! hope this will be useful for people using CI

Comment: @ClainDsilva: It's not Codeigniter that does that, it's the database. I would guess that you are using MySQL as database, it will replace any invalid date with a zero date. SQL Server for example would throw an error instead.

Comment: @Guffa my point is about using a null as an non string parameter in CI without causing an error. The later one is known globally that any invalid date is taken as 0000-00-00 00:00:00 by mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateapproved = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
```